# Call javascript on RedirectToAction

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to call a javascript function when a user has successfully been redirected to a new view?

I have tried the following-

**C#**

```
if (Session["UserId"])
{
      return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");
}
```

**cshtml**

```
@if (Session["UserId"] != null)
{
    <script>$('#btnTest').click();</script>

}
```

**Fails with**

```
 JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined
```

I have referenced jquery in the project and tested it just with a button click and this works however the above is failing. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what does the rendered markup (html on client side) look like? and where is it referencing jQuery? because the alert alone does not require any library.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Most likely, this HTML is being inserted before jQuery is actually called. For example, if you're not referencing jQuery until the closing body tag, then this is being run before jQuery exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, this HTML is being inserted before jQuery is actually referenced. For example, if you're not referencing jQuery until the closing body tag (as you should), then this will be run before jQuery actually exists. The best way to handle this type of thing is with sections. You can defined a section in your layout for scripts and then ensure that that section is below required dependencies like jQuery.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
    <script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

**AwesomeView.cshtml**

```
@section Scripts
{
    @if (Session["UserId"] != null)
    {
        <script>$('#btnTest').click();</script>
    }
}
```

This will result in the following HTML being generated (assuming the session variable isn't null of course:

```
    <script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>$('#btnTest').click();</script>
</body>
```

It's important to note that this only works with standard views. Partial views cannot define sections, so if you need to include some bit of script inside a partial, you'll have to take a different approach to deferring execution. Generally, the best method at that point is simply utilize `window.onload` directly:

```
var onload = window.onload
window.onload = function () {
    onload();
    // your code here
}
```

That should ensure that jQuery has already been loaded. However, it's really better to just not include JS code in partials, in the first place. There's a number of issues that can result from that and it makes your code very fragmented and brittle, in general.